# Authorization header is blocked in java 11, tomcat 9?

Tags: spring-mvc, authorization, java-11, tomcat9

we have a Apache, Tomcat 9, Java 8, Spring MVC 4.3 website. Working well.

Now we are to migrate to java 11, spring 5. All working well, except on 1 test server the autorization header (containing a bearer token) is not 'visible' in the java code. When testing using curl we see that other headers, like f.i. authorisation (z -> s) are visible.

Our devops claim that there are no diffs in tomcat config between the J8 and J11 set up.

So somehow somewhere this specific server is blocking the authorization header (but does not block it in java 8, spring 4)

Any ideas where the issue could be?